# Permanently disabling horizontal scroll? Out of ideas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Alright, I've pretty much hit rock bottom with this one.  This mobile site keeps generating horizontal scroll bars every time I hover over a working link.  When the navigation drawer is out, it ends up overriding the overflow property, which is breaking my site.  Overflow:hidden; isn't really doing anything for me.

I have no idea where the issue is coming from, so all I can do is link the site and hope someone way smarter than me can help figure it out.  In the meantime, is there any sort of jQuery hack to completely disable horizontal scrolling?  I would even be okay with disabling scrolling all together when the nav drawer is out.

Heres the site http://www.helloimmatt.com

It's still in very rough shape, but resize down to mobile and pull out the nav drawer to see the issue.  Thanks in advance, I'm stumped.

Comment: An invalid but working way to disable horizontal scrolling is to put `overflow-x:hidden;` to `<body>`. As to deal with your problem correctly, I can't help :-)

Comment: Oh and you should test the site on a real phone (with swipes and taps instead of clicks and hovers).

Comment: Yeah, that disables the scrollbar but you are still able to scroll through the site, it's especially apparent on mobile phones like you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

or

```
$("body").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
```

Also, you can try diable using JQuery (or javascript, if you like)

I made jsfiddle with example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Kvn7t/1/

Comment: That gets rid of the horizontal scroll bar, but the user is still able to scroll through the page.  It's more apparent on mobile phones or laptops with trackpads.